# opencv highgui error

Tags: c++, opencv

I installed the library opencv in my ubuntu pc and i wrote a program that takes a video from a webcam and it works.

Yesterday I installed the driver for video capture "media_build" to take a video from a video grabber, but the same program doesn't work, while if I open "video for linux 2" on VLC it works.

This is the error:

> libv4l2: error set_fmt gave us a different result then try_fmt!
>   HIGHGUI ERROR: libv4l unable convert to requested pixfmt
>   HIGHGUI ERROR: V4L: device /dev/video0: Unable to query number of channels
>   ERROR: capture is NULL

The instruction is:

> CvCapture* capture = cvCaptureFromCAM( CV_CAP_ANY );

any suggestion?
thanks

Comment: Try [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/).

Answer (score 1):

I think your program is crashing. If so you can add `if(capture!=NULL)
{// your normal code here}else{// display some error message}`. In this case the program wont crash. Probably your video driver isn't providing a interface known to openCv.

Comment: Thanks, so there isn't a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use this command:

```
sudo chmod 666 /dev/video0
```